# Typescript async/await not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, sequelize.js

I've a problem about async/await on typescript with target es2017. Below is my code :

my route.ts :

```
method: 'POST',
        config: {            
            auth: {
                strategy: 'token',        
            }
        },
        path: '/users',
        handler: (request, reply) {

    let { username, password } = request.payload;

    const getOperation = User
    .findAll({
        where: {
            username: username
        }
    })
    .then(([User]) => {
        if(!User) {
            reply({
                error: true,
                errMessage: 'The specified user was not found'
            });
            return;
        }

        let comparedPassword = compareHashPassword(User.password, password);
        console.log(comparedPassword);

        if(comparedPassword) {
            const token = jwt.sign({
                username,
                scope: User.id

            }, 'iJiYpmaVwXMp8PpzPkWqc9ShQ5UhyEfy', {
                algorithm: 'HS256',
                expiresIn: '1h'
            });

            reply({
                token,
                scope: User.id
            });
        } else {
            reply('incorrect password');
        }
    } )
    .catch(error => { reply('server-side error') });

};
```

my helper.ts :

```
export async function compareHashPassword(pw:string, originalPw:string) {
    console.log(pw);
    console.log(originalPw);
    let compared = bcrypt.compare(originalPw, pw, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) {
                return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(isMatch);
        return isMatch;
        });

    return await compared;
}
```

this auth route supposed to return JWT token when user login. but the problem here is even when I enter the valid password to sign-in the function compareHashPassword always return undefined.

For example when i call the api with json string

```
{
  "username": "x",
  "password": "helloword"
}
```

When i track using console.log(), the log is :

```
$2a$10$Y9wkjblablabla -> hashed password stored in db
helloword 
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: bound ] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
true
```

maybe this is just my lack of understanding about using async/await with typescript. for note my env is :

```
node : v8.6.0
typescript : v2.5.2
ts-node : v3.3.0
my tsconfig.json //
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "removeComments": true,
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "classic"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order for async/await to work, an async function has to return a `Promise`. Also, you must call an `async` with the await keyword this way:

***You can only call await inside an async function, so I wrapped it in an async func***

```
const someFunc = async function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        setTimeout(resolve, 100, true);
    });
};

(async () => {
     const result = await someFunc(); // true
})();
```

You are not satisfying any of these rules in your `compareHashPassword` declaration and the way you call it.

This is how I would rewrite your code :

```
export async function compareHashPassword(pw:string, originalPw:string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(originalPw, pw, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log(isMatch);
            resolve(isMatch);
        });
    });
}

// and call it this way
(async () => {
     const compared = await compareHashPassword(pw, originPw);
})()
```

Have a look at this async await blog post:
https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

And this blog post for Promises:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Also as @Patrick Roberts mentioned, you can use `util.promisify` to turn an async callback style function into a Promise, this is `node 8.xx` otherwise you can use `bluebird` package which has a similar functionality.

Hope this helps

Comment: _As for now, you can only call await inside an async function_ As per the specification, that will **always** be the case, just saying.

Comment: I find that sad, although I didn't check the implementation itself in v8. Thanks for the tip, I will update my answer

Comment: By the way, in your first example, the `Promise.resolve(...)` is redundant. All you have to do is `return true` and the `async` function will implicitly coerce it into a resolved promise.

Comment: I dind't know that, so explicitely return a Promise only needs to be done when having a callback style async call ?

Comment: Yes, or in node.js you have the option of using `util.promisify()` to convert callback-style functions into promise-style functions. See my answer for usage.

Comment: Now your `new Promise()` is no longer redundant, but I personally prefer writing it like this `setTimeout(resolve, 100, true);` Just food for thought~

Answer (score 5):

Since you're targeting ES2017, let's clean up your code, starting with the simpler `helper.ts`:

```
import { promisify } from 'util' // you'll thank me later

const compare = promisify(bcrypt.compare)

export async function compareHashPassword(pw:string, originalPw:string) {
    console.log(pw);
    console.log(originalPw);
    return compare(originalPw, pw);
}
```

Now for the `route.ts`:

```
handler: async (request, reply) => {
  let { username, password } = request.payload;

  try {
    const [user] = await User.findAll({
      where: {
        username: username
      }
    })

    if(!user) {
      reply({
        error: true,
        errMessage: 'The specified user was not found'
      });

      return;
    }

    let match = await compareHashPassword(user.password, password);

    console.log(match);

    if (match) {
      const token = jwt.sign({
        username,
        scope: User.id
      }, 'iJiYpmaVwXMp8PpzPkWqc9ShQ5UhyEfy', {
        algorithm: 'HS256',
        expiresIn: '1h'
      });

      reply({
        token,
        scope: user.id
      });
    } else {
      reply('incorrect password');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    reply('server-side error')
  }
}
```

Hopefully I've matched what you're attempting to accomplish, based on the code you've provided. If there's an issue somewhere with this updated code, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: wow, that's really helpful utility from node. Thanks for all your answer. Both of your solution worked and help me understand how async works. cheers.